# How can I run two Django versions in the same server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, python, django, mod-wsgi

i've got two web apps. One was developed using Django 1.0 and the other using Django 1.4. How can I run both apps in the same apache2 server using two versions of django? Somebody told me something about virtualenv ... 
I'm using mod_wsgi.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely go with virtualenv.

This is how you can check if you already have virtualenv installed:

```
$ virtualenv --version
```

If you don't have virtualenv installed, you can install it like this:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
```

If that gives you an error, you probably don't have pip yet. You can install it using:

```
$ easy_install pip
```

Once virtualenv is installed you can create separated virtual Python environments, one per Django installation, like this:

```
$ virtualenv env
```

I recommend running this command in the project folder of each app. If you do so, you get a folder called 'env' which will contain the virtual Python environment. Every time you want to start working with the virtual environment you can issue this command:

```
$ source env/bin/activate
```

Your prompt should indicate that you are running the environment by looking something like this:

```
(env)$
```

You can leave the virtualenv by typing:

```
(env)$ deactivate
```

If you have come this far you can start installing environment-specific versions of Python packages like this (in an activated environment):

```
(env)$ pip install Django==1.0
```

This will install Django version 1.0 inside the current virtual environment. You can see if it worked by issuing:

```
(env)$ pip freeze
```

This should result in something like:

```
Django==1.0-final
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

You can now deactivate this environment, activate the other environment, and install Django 1.4 like this:

```
(env)$ pip install Django==1.4
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Amending to this, in your `WSGIDaemonProcess` line, you add a `python-path=/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.x/site-packages` to make this work with `mod_wsgi` too.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read any of the available documentation, including:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments
http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Delegation_To_Daemon_Process
http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango